# Running TestNG tests again and again programmatically

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng

I have two test cases TC1 and TC2 and trying to execute these two test cases three times in following manner:
TC1
TC2
TC1
TC2
TC1
TC2

i tried with following code using @factory:

```
public class ClassName {@Test(priority = 1,invocationCount = 1)
// TC1
public void verifyQuestionTitle(){
    try {
        .....
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test(priority = 2,invocationCount = 1)
// TC2
public void verifyAnswerOptionsCount(){
    try {
        .....
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Factory
public Object[] create(){
    return new Object[]{
            new ClassName (), new ClassName (), new ClassName ()
    };
}
```

But this result in execution of TC1 three times first and then TC2 three times i.e.
TC1
TC1
TC1
TC2
TC2
TC2
which is different than i desire. using the invocation count to 3 also result in same pattern.
Can anyone help me achieving what i am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It should work as expected if you use the `group-by-instances` feature: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods